# Is the empty set, ∅, "included" in the set, {1, 2, 3, 4}?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

This was a question asked by my professor in a quiz. I answered the question as false (which was marked incorrect). I did this because the empty set is not "included" in the set (in my interpretation). Rather, it is a subset of the given set. If the original set was {∅, 1, 2, 3, 4}, then I would believe the answer to be true as ∅ is included as an element. Likewise, if the question was phrased “The empty set is a SUBSET of the set…” I would have answered true.

My professor argued that *"included in a set"* means *"subset of a set."* In contrast, I believe it to closer represent *"is an element of a set."* He also argued that for something to be a subset of a set, it also must be an element of that set, stating that ∅ is an element of EVERY set, which is an objectively a false statement.

He has also claimed things such as *∅ = {∅}* and *{1, 2, 3} = {∅, 1, 2, 3}* which I also believe to be false.

If anyone has any insight or advice, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As you describe it, your professor's POV is wrong. You seem to fully understand the concept, in contrast to him. You are right that “being included” is ambiguous and should be avoided. Your professor should have given you points for your answer because of this ambiguity.

Comment: In my experience, "included" refers to the $\in$ relation, and "contained in" refers to the $\subseteq$ relation. I guess I could see how one might swap them around just because of how English is sometimes, but I've never heard anyone use them the other way around so... (Consequently, I'd say the ambiguity should be interpreted in your favor and yield you points. For whatever that sentiment means from an internet stranger.)

Comment: "He has also claimed things such as ∅ = {∅} and {1, 2, 3} = {∅, 1, 2, 3} which I also believe to be false." -- Yeah your prof is ***completely*** in the wrong on these.

Comment: Do you have a textbook or at least published notes? If so, find the definitions you think your professor is not using properly and show him the definitions. If you don't have a reference book or notes, but you have access to a library, do the same.

Comment: If your professor's interpretation that $\emptyset$ can be thought of as existing as an element of every set and that its presence can be omitted or ignored... then things such as [Von Neumann's definition of natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers) would look like nonsense... yet this is widely accepted by the mathematical community at large to be a valid way to define our natural numbers.

Comment: Unfortunately, the terminology is not so uniform... For e.g. [Enderton](https://docs.ufpr.br/~hoefel/ensino/CM304_CompleMat_PE3/livros/Enderton_Elements%20of%20set%20theory_%281977%29.pdf) "the inclusion relation ( $\subseteq$)..." (page 3). Having said that, as ∅ = {∅} and {1, 2, 3} = {∅, 1, 2, 3} are wrong.

Comment: @PrincessEev: For what's its worth, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_(mathematics)#Notation_and_terminology) states that 'George Boolos strongly urged that "contains" be used for membership only, and "includes" for the subset relation only.' I have certainly heard people use "contains" in the opposite sense to what your comment says, e.g. "the set $\{0,1\}$ contains $2$ elements". Likewise, I have heard the symbol $\subseteq$ being referred to as the inclusion relation. I think both of these words can be ambiguous, without further context.

Comment: On $\emptyset \ne \{\emptyset\}$ stands almost all mathematics for last nearly hundred years.

Comment: Terminology may not be uniform, but basic facts such as $\emptyset\neq \{\emptyset\}$ should be universally agreed on...  "*If anyone has...advice*"  Assuming you are at a school with multiple professors, I would approach another professor or the department chair and have them try to reason with them rather than trying to do this during class.

Comment: **All set  $S$ is distinct of the set of its subsets (or parts) $P(S)$. The empty set belongs to  $P(S)$**